# Calculate missing values in an array from adjacent values

Tags: ruby, math

Given an array

[50,30,0,0,10,0,30,60,0]

I need to replace the zeroes with calculated values to create a 'curve', so for example, between 10 and 30, the zero could be replaced with 20.

I keep thinking there must be a cool ruby way of doing this, but I cant find one. Can anyone help? The solution needs to take into account multiple adjacent zeroes, and zeroes at the start and end of the range.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Post what you would expect the answer to be for the array that you gave.

Comment: Can you clarify what `[50,0,0,10]` and `[50,0,0,0,10]` should become? Linear interpolation all the way along?

Comment: jdl: output should be something like [50,30,20,15,10,20,30,60,80]. does that help you too phrogz?

Comment: @phrogz yes linear interpolation all the way along.

Comment: @jdee That is not linear interpolation; interpolating between 30 and 10 over two steps would result in stepping by 6.66 each time in linear interpolation. You need better specifications. Further, where on earth do you get the value of `80` from?

Comment: I  hope you never need zero as a real value ...:D

Comment: Looks to me like you want non-parametric interpolation (perhaps a  spline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you seem to be unaware of is [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). The Wikipedia article is a good place to start - exactly what algoithm is best suited to you depends on the exact context of your problem so we can't give you the one true answer here.

Comment: how about linear interpolation.

Comment: its written in big letters at the top of this page. have a read why dont you.

Comment: @jdee You are expecting a certain level of mind reading here. No one else know what problem you are trying to solve. You ask for linear interpolation and then provide an example answer which doesn't use linear interpolation. Explain more clearly the problem you are trying to solve (not the array involved) and you will likely get better answers.

Comment: I just needed a solution to fill in the zeroes, the specifics of what interpolation type and the results it generates are pretty incidental to me. I should have probably made that clearer. I suppose I'm doing that now. No solutions provided gave me anything close to what was required but I found this http://jcj.net/?p=18 that does the trick. I'm marking Pauls answer as best.

Answer (score 1):

```
a =[50,30,0,0,10,0,30,60,0]

a.each_index{|i| a[i] = a[i-1] - ((a[i-2] - a[i-1])/2).to_i if a[i] == 0 && i > 1 }

puts a.inspect # [50, 30, 20, 15, 10, 8, 30, 60, 75]
```

I can't work out why the last number might be 80 in your spec however? Plus it doesn't work for the first two items in the array.

Comment: What is that, a low-pass filter interpolation? (You step from 30 to 10 first by 10 and then by 5.)

Answer (score 1):

If there could not be consecutive zeroes, this unintelligible one-liner would do the trick (`list` is the given list of numbers):

```
[0, *list, 0].each_cons(3).map { |p, x, n| x == 0 ? (p + n)/2 : x }
```

Ruby 1.9 only, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_consecutive_values( array, value=nil )
  raise "Need a value or block to find" unless value || block_given?
  start = last = nil
  ranges = []
  indices = array.each_with_index do |o,i|
    if ((block_given? && yield(o)) || o==value)
      start = i unless start
      last = i
    else
      ranges << (start..last) if start && last
      start = last = nil
    end
  end
  ranges << (start..last) if start && last
  ranges
end

def interpolate_zeros( array, round=false )
  result = array.dup
  find_consecutive_values( array, 0 ).each do |range|
    next unless range.first>0 && range.last<(array.length-1)
    before = result[range.first - 1]
    after  = result[range.last  + 1]
    diff   = after - before
    size   = (range.last - range.first + 2).to_f
    range.each_with_index do |i,idx|
      value = before + diff * (idx+1)/size
      value = value.round if round
      result[i] = value
    end
  end
  result
end

p interpolate_zeros( [0,50,30,0,0,10,0,30,60,0], true )
#=> [0, 50, 30, 23, 17, 10, 20, 30, 60, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question. There is a ruby gem "interpolator", which just does what you want and probably tons more:

http://interpolator.rubyforge.org.

Here is a short introduction:

http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/ruby-interpolation-with-gem-interpolator/